# how to change background color of column header for AdvancedDataGrid control in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have below columnGroup in advancedDataGrid control and I want to show the header in red background color and also applied the style but the **background color** in the **header** does not show as red only the text color in the header is changed.

```
 <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup textAlign="center"  headerStyleName="myHeaderStyles" >
```

....

I also have the following style defined

```
<mx:Style>
   .myHeaderStyles {
        color: red;
        fontWeight: bold;
        background-color:red;
        background-disabled-color:red;
        area-fill:true;

    }

</mx:Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try doing this

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid headerColors="[red]"
```

Comment: i tried header-colors style on the grid it works, but it does not work on individual column header. i have grouped columns and i would like to apply the style to a particular column header but it does not work it works for all headers at the grid level though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might have to extend the column class.  This article is for the DataGridColumn but maybe it will help.

http://ntt.cc/2009/02/18/set-background-color-for-headers-of-datagrid.html